# I get an out of bounds error for the array but i dont understand why, error at line 23

Tags: java

I'm new to 2D arrays and I'm trying to input a specific value in all the coordinates so i made a loop, but for some reason it just keep going until it says that its out of bounds as if the loop isn't closing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Number of rows: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Number or columns: ");
        int columns = input.nextInt();

        double[][] planets = new double[columns][rows];

        int columns_loop = 0;
        while (columns_loop <= columns) {
            int rows_loop=0;

            while (rows_loop<=rows) {
                System.out.println("Enter Rainfall (in mm): ");
                double rows_input=input.nextDouble();
                planets[columns_loop][rows_loop] = rows_input;
                rows_loop++;
            }
            columns_loop++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: arrys in java are zero based. so `(columns_loop <columns)` and `rows_loop<rows`

Comment: Besides other problems with this post, please label what line is line 23 (you can put a comment on that line).

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes as it is a localized homework question.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is in your loops.  See comments.

```
        while (columns_loop <= columns) { // should be < columns
            int rows_loop=0;

            while (rows_loop<=rows) { // should be < rows
                System.out.println("Enter Rainfall (in mm): ");
                double rows_input=input.nextDouble();
                planets[columns_loop][rows_loop] = rows_input;
                rows_loop++;
            }
            columns_loop++;
        }
```

Arrays are zero based in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple mistake, but when using arrays, the index is always starting at [0] so when you call you while loop simply change it to :

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Number of rows: ");
    int rows = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Number or columns: ");
    int columns = input.nextInt();

    double[][] planets = new double[columns][rows];

    int columns_loop = 0;
    while (columns_loop < columns) {
        int rows_loop=0;

        while (rows_loop < rows) {
            System.out.println("Enter Rainfall (in mm): ");
            double rows_input=input.nextDouble();
            planets[columns_loop][rows_loop] = rows_input;
            rows_loop++;
        }
        columns_loop++;
    }

}
```

This should fix that error and run correctly.